# How to hook into get_files function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a problem manipulating data on a wordpress page without editing the code directly. Is there way to for example access this page https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/theme-editor.php and tell function get_files not to load up 404.php for example? I've used filters and hooks before but I feel lost in this particular case.

I have tried to hook into get_files to change the loop.

```
function yur_function()
    unset($allowed_files["404.php"]);
}

add_action('get_files', 'yur_function');
```

Something like this.

Comment: Can you explain what actual _problem_ you are trying to solve here to begin with?

Comment: Why do you need / want to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to modify some functionality in pages in wordpress for a client without changing the default .php files because I was under the impression they would override during updates etc. Similar to how people add things to init etc but on individual pages.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no hook in to that function so it's not really easy to modify that list of files.
get_files is defined in wp-includes/class-wp-theme.php and doesn't use apply_filters at all.

Comment: Not only is it _"not really easy"_, it is _impossible_ to edit the "allowed files" list.  Additionally, there doesn't appear to be ANY other hooks or filters to intercept / prevent editing a file....